# Collapse Column in R

Tags: r

I have searched as best I could, and part of my problem is that I'm really not sure exactly what to ask. Here's my data, and how I want it to end up:

Now:

```
john    a Yes
john    b No
john    c No
Rebekah a Yes
Rebekah d No
Chase   c Yes
Chase   d No
Chase   e No
Chase   f No
```

How I'd like it to be:

```
john     a,b,c    Yes
Rebekah  a,d      Yes
Chase    c,d,e,f  Yes
```

Notice that the 3rd column says yes when it is the first row with that particular value in the 1st column. The 3rd row isn't necessary, I was just using it, thinking that I would try to do this all with `if` and `for` statements, but I thought that would be so inefficient. Is there any way to make this work efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option would be *(using data mentioned by @bgoldst)*

```
library('dplyr')

out = df %>% 
      group_by(a) %>% 
      summarize(b = paste(unique(c(b)), collapse=","), c = "yes")

#> out
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

#        a       b   c
#1   Chase c,d,e,f yes
#2 Rebekah     a,d yes
#3    john   a,b,c yes
```

using `data.table`

```
out = setDT(df)[, .(b = paste(unique(b),  collapse=','), c = "yes"), by = .(a)]

#> out
#         a       b   c
#1:    john   a,b,c yes
#2: Rebekah     a,d yes
#3:   Chase c,d,e,f yes
```

Comment: This second data.table worked for me very well, but I'm not sure why. Could you help me with the syntax? I'm trying now to get rid of any duplicates. For instance, if position 3,2 of the data frame were b, I would like the position 1,2 of the new data frame to read "a,b". Thanks.

Comment: In that case you need to add `unique`. check my answer I just edited it

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`by()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html) to do this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c('john','john','john','Rebekah','Rebekah','Chase','Chase','Chase','Chase'), b=c('a','b','c','a','d','c','d','e','f'), c=c('Yes','No','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','No','No'), stringsAsFactors=F );
do.call(rbind,by(df,df$a,function(x) data.frame(a=x$a[1],b=paste0(x$b,collapse=','),c=x$c[1],stringsAsFactors=F)));
##               a       b   c
## Chase     Chase c,d,e,f Yes
## john       john   a,b,c Yes
## Rebekah Rebekah     a,d Yes
```

**Edit:** Here's another approach, using independent aggregations using `tapply()`:

```
key <- unique(df$a);
data.frame(a=key,b=tapply(df$b,df$a,paste,collapse=',')[key],c=tapply(df$c,df$a,`[`,1)[key]);
##               a       b   c
## john       john   a,b,c Yes
## Rebekah Rebekah     a,d Yes
## Chase     Chase c,d,e,f Yes
```

**Edit:** And yet another approach, `merge()`ing the result of a couple of `aggregate()` calls:

```
merge(aggregate(b~a,df,paste,collapse=','),aggregate(c~a,df,`[`,1));
##         a       b   c
## 1   Chase c,d,e,f Yes
## 2    john   a,b,c Yes
## 3 Rebekah     a,d Yes
```